# ClassNotFoundException when dragging and dropping MBO [Sybase]

Tags: jdbc, sybase

I have pinged successfully and managed to connect to the Microsoft SQL server, however when I tried to drag and drop a MBO into the diagram, it's giving the error as below.

[image: error pop up]

I have downloaded **sqljdbc4.jar** and **sqljdbc.jar** and put them in the folder listed below(at the server side and my local copy) as advised in other threads / forum.

I have also restarted the Sybase Unwired Platform Services and restarted the server but to no avail. Any help to solve this error would be appreciated.

> C:\sybase\UnwiredPlatform\Unwired_WorkSpace\Eclipse\sybase_workspace\mobile\eclipse\plugins\com.sybase.uep.com.sqlserver_2.1.0.201109131337\lib
>   C:\sybase\UnwiredPlatform\Servers\UnwiredServer\lib\3rdparty

Comment: You only need `sqljdbc4.jar` (if on Java 6 or higher).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel thanks, I have removed the non-related files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to solve it by putting the sqljdbc4.jar in this folder.

> C:\Sybase\UnwiredPlatform\MobileSDK213\Unwired_WorkSpace\Eclipse\sybase_workspace\mobile\eclipse\plugins\com.sybase.uep.com.sqlserver_2.1.3.201207271225\lib\